# Make multiple requests with different data

Tags: angularjs

I want to make multiple requests where the data appends the title with a number. But instead of e.g. "Hello 1", "Hello 2", "Hello 3", "Hello 4" I get "Hello 4", "Hello 4", "Hello 4", "Hello 4".

`console.log(item.title);` shows "Hello 1", "Hello 2", "Hello 3", "Hello 4" correctly in the console.

I am guessing that it is because the request are asynchronous.

```
vm.title = vm.case.title;
for (let i = 1; i <= vm.number_of_cases_to_create; i++) {
    vm.createNewCase(i, vm.case);
}

function createNewCase(number, item) {
    item.title = vm.title + ' ' + number;
    console.log(item.title);

    CaseProvider.create(item).then(function (case) {
        console.log(case.id);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, that is an async consequence. On the line `vm.createNewCase(i, vm.case)` you send the same object to the method `createNewCase` and when async starts, it refers to the same object, so all calls use the same "Hello 4" value.

I propose to pass a copy of `vm.case` to your method, then code sample should work as expected. There is [a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object) about object cloning in javascript.

Comment: Thanks, it put me on the right track. I used `angular.copy` to make a copy of the original object https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/docs/api/ng/function/angular.copy.